# How can I fix an error in nonlinear regression: nls function

Tags: r, nls

I am using the below commands in R:

```
attach(Puromycin)
Puromycin
plot(Puromycin$conc,Puromycin$rate)
mm=function(conc,vmax,k) vmax*conc/(k+conc)
mm
mm1=nls(rate~mm(conc,vmax,k),data=Puromycin,
        start=c(vmax=50,k=0.05),subset=state=="treated”)
mm1
```

Unfortunately,  I receive the below error:

```
Error: unexpected input in "mm1=nls(rate~mm(conc,vmax,k),data=Puromycin,start=c(vmax=50,k=0.05),subset=state==”"
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hi vahid, it looks like you've got curly quotation marks. Try replacing `state=="treated”` with `state == 'treated'` If you're using Mac, you can [turn type of this autocomplete off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/how-to-disable-smart-quotes).

Comment: Thank you. You're correct. It has now been fixed.

Comment: @vahid: More generally you should switch away from using a word processing program to do your program editing. Instead use an editor designed for programming.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete solution, with fitted line plotted.

```
data(Puromycin)

mm <- function(conc, vmax, k) vmax*conc/(k + conc)

mm1 <- nls(rate ~ mm(conc,vmax,k), data = Puromycin,
        start = list(vmax = 50, k = 0.05),
        subset = state == "treated")
summary(mm1)

with(Puromycin, plot(conc, rate))
x <- with(Puromycin, seq(min(conc), max(conc), length.out = 100))
y <- predict(mm1, newdata = data.frame(conc = x), se = FALSE)
lines(x, y, col = "blue")
```

[image]